# 外部JSライブラリをvue-cli 3で使うには

Tags: javascript, vue.js

UMD(UniversalModelDefinition）で定義されている外部JSライブラリを、vue-cli 3で使うにはどうすれば良いでしょうか。
ライブラリは自分のリポジトリに置いて使います。
vue-cliを使うまでは、index.htmlからscriptタグで読み込んで使っていました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ライブラリは自分のリポジトリに置いて使います。

が何を指しているのか曖昧ですが、UMDということなので通常のよくあるライブラリ同様に使用できます。

### 自分の他のGitHubリポジトリ(または任意のgitリモートリポジトリ)に置いている

```
npm install [git url]
```

などでその[パッケージをプロジェクトに追加](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)して使いたい箇所で`import`する（または`require`）.

```
import hoge from 'example';
```

や

```
import hoge from 'example/lib/example';
```

など

### 使いたいプロジェクトの同じリポジトリ内に存在している

そのまま`import`できます。

```
import hoge from './lib/example';
```

など

---

その他、当てはまらない場合などは追加情報をください。